Problem with navigation stack not binding to variable in path array that has been bound twice
Rather than creating multiple Coordinator class files
Create a manager to manage the coordinators centrally
I would like to access the Coordinator via the Manager to add or delete navigation passes.
However, the value of the path variable changes when adding or deleting the Coordinator's path accessed through the manager, but the NavigationStack's path does not bind it properly.
Even if the path variable of the NavigationStack changes, the view does not change, but the navigation screen moves when the app returns from the background to the foreground.
If I use the @Observable macro on the Coordinator class it works fine, but I hope this class will work in iOS16.
Is there any solution in this situation?
The code is complicated, so it will be replaced with the github address.
here is sourcode
ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var coordinatorManager = CoordinatorManager()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $coordinatorManager.firstCoordinator.path) {
            Button("add Color") {
                coordinatorManager.firstCoordinator.push(.red)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
                Text("\(color)")
            }
        }
    }
}

CoordinatorManager.swift
class CoordinatorManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstCoordinator = Coordinator()
}

Coordinator.swift
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Color] = []
    
    func push(_ color: Color) {
        path.append(color)
    }
}

Coordinator.swift
ObservableObject -> Using @Observable macro "works"
However, the @Observable macro can be used in iOS 17 or later.

"The code is complicated, so it will be replaced with the github address." No, you should isolate the problem and create a [mcve].

try making Coordinator a struct, because nesting ObservableObject can create issues, i.e you must update them manually.
